# Apollonius Graphs (Delaunay Graphs of Disks) in sfcgal or PostGIS?

Tags: postgis, sfcgal, delaunay, tesselation

I was wondering if there is support for Delaunay Graphs of Disks (a.k.a. Apollonius Graphs) in PostGIS/sfcgal?

A [CGAL function](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Apollonius_graph_2/index.html) seems to exist for this. But I can't seem to find it in the PostGIS ecosystem. (I haven't used SFCGAL much, except for having it installed from source with the latest PostGIS 2.5.)

I also found a figure in a related [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16026766/683218):

[image]

So, does a function for this generalized Delaunay Graph exist?

If not, could someone with the experience provide some pointers as to how to add it to a custom-build SFCGAL? Ideally, I'm looking for schematics of how SFCGAL interfaced a similar Delaunay function that I can try to follow to add the above linked CGAL function.

(I'm interested in obtaining the generalized Delaunay tessellation. Not sure if I used the terminology right).

Comment: Nice question. I have used sfcgal a bit, but not looked at the cgal manual before -- amazing stuff there. I believe that Oslandia did the wrappers for Postgis. Not sure if anyone from there is on here. Out of interest, what GIS/spatial problem are you using this to solve?

Comment: @JohnPowellakaBarça Thanks for the pointers. I'm currently still in the exploration stage on computational geometric operations like these and have only a guess that it could be used in transportation potentially. I wanted to see if it's possible to have it working at the database level before delving into the plumbings of C++:). Haven't generated any of these diagrams before.

Comment: Enjoy. I have now done quite a bit with sfcgal, very nice functionality, but lack the C++ skills to do my own wrapers :-(